# Apache HttpComponents v5.2 HTTP client always closing connections with TCP RESETs

Tags: java, tcp, httpclient, apache-httpclient-5.x

JRE: OpenLogic OpenJdk 8u352

OS: Windows Server 2019

I have a simple Java 8 project. It is a HTTP client that connects to github.com, receives a 200 OK response back, and closes the connection.

The only libraries being used are the ones included in Apache HttpComponents HttpClient 5.2.1 (httpclient5-5.2.1.jar, httpcore5-5.2.jar, slf4j-api-1.7.36, etc.). No other libraries are included in the project. The code is copied directly from the Apache quick start guide located here: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.2.x/quickstart.html

The issue is that my client application is starting the FIN/ACK sequence after receiving the response from github, but then immediately following up with a TCP RESET without letting the FIN/ACK sequence finish. Why is the client sending a RESET instead of letting the FIN/ACK finish normally? Is there a programmatic way of ensuring the client always closes with a FIN/ACK and does not initiate a TCP RESET? A screenshot of the wireshark trace is below. The code is below as well.

I get the same results whether running it as a runnable .jar on a different server, running it within eclipse, or running it within a Tomcat container in a separate project (Tomcat runs on different server). Either way, it always ends with a TCP RESET.

[Wireshark Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDfwG.png)

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClients;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.ClassicHttpRequest;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.io.entity.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.io.support.ClassicRequestBuilder;

public class ApacheHttpTesting {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
        ClassicHttpRequest httpGet = ClassicRequestBuilder.get(https://www.github.com)
                .build();
        // The underlying HTTP connection is still held by the response object
        // to allow the response content to be streamed directly from the network socket.
        // In order to ensure correct deallocation of system resources
        // the user MUST call CloseableHttpResponse#close() from a finally clause.
        // Please note that if response content is not fully consumed the underlying
        // connection cannot be safely re-used and will be shut down and discarded
        // by the connection manager.
        httpclient.execute(httpGet, response -> {
            System.out.println(response.getCode() + " " + response.getReasonPhrase());
            final HttpEntity entity1 = response.getEntity();
            // do something useful with the response body
            // and ensure it is fully consumed
            EntityUtils.consume(entity1);
            response.close();
            return null;
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```